# Changing variable in a function

Tags: python, variables

```
from random import randint

count = 0
Validation = False

def generateNumber():
    Number = randint(1, 10)
    return Number

def checkNumber(Guess):
    Number = generateNumber()
    if int(Guess) == Number and count < 1:
        return "First time right! Genius?"
        Validation = True

    elif int(Guess) == Number and count == 2:
        return "Correct. Second time, nice!"
        Validation = True
    elif int(Guess) == Number and count < 4:
        return "Correct. Good job."
        Validation = True
    elif int(Guess) == Number and count > 3:
        return "Correct. Took you long enough."
        Validation = True
    else:
        return "Wrong! Try again "

while Validation == False:
    Guess = input("Please guess a number between 1 to 10: ")
    print (checkNumber(Guess))
    count += 1
else:
    TryAgain = input("Would you like to try again? y/n \n")
```

So the problem is, that when the user guesses the right number. Validation should be turned to True. So the while loop will stop looping. But the variable validation doesn't turn True when the player guesses the right number.

Comment: Validation is considered local unless you prefix it with global. If you wish to reference your global Validation from a function, you need to declare it like so: `global Validation` in the function, this way when you change the value it will be persistant

Comment: Hmm. when I add global to it, wether I do it in the function itself, in the variable declaration on top, or on the while loop. It gives me a bad syntax error.

Comment: Another major problem in your code is that you return a string, effectively breaking the function before you set the Validation field. Please see my answer for the correct order (`Validation = True` only than `return "..."`)

Comment: As an aside, having your functions return human-readable status information isn't a very good design (unless producing a human-readable message is the function's *sole* purpose). For modular program design, you want functions to return a value which is meaningful to the computer, such as `True` or `False` for this particular function, and have the human/computer interaction as the main function or program flow, at the outside perimeter of the program. Seeing how exactly this is useful comes later in your learning process, but it's good to note already.

Comment: You change the number every time.  What you have here is a problem with state, therefore maybe a class instance would be better than a bunch of global variables.  Or you could just make the function fully defined by its input and output, by passing in all the globals as actual function parameters, and returning multiple values as a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables in Python are a bit tricky, it is not enough to declare a variable at the top of the file.

Also, keep you return the value before you set the Validation value, causing the function to terminate before setting this variable

Last issue is the while logic, see correction for using raw_input instead of input and else indentation

Read only access to global variables work as expected, yet when changing their value in a function requires one extra step, you should declare the global variable as global. In your case:

```
def generateNumber():
    Number = randint(1, 10)
    return Number

def checkNumber(Guess):
    global Validation #<-- this instructs Python to use the global variable
    Number = generateNumber()
    if int(Guess) == Number and count < 1:
        Validation = True
        return "First time right! Genius?"

    elif int(Guess) == Number and count == 2:
        Validation = True
        return "Correct. Second time, nice!"

    elif int(Guess) == Number and count < 4:
        Validation = True
        return "Correct. Good job."

    elif int(Guess) == Number and count > 3:
        Validation = True
        return "Correct. Took you long enough."

    else:
        return "Wrong! Try again "

while Validation == False:
    Guess = input("Please guess a number between 1 to 10: ")
    print (checkNumber(Guess))
    count += 1
    if (Validation):
        if (raw_input("Would you like to try again? y/n \n") == "y"):
            count = 0
            Validation = False
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set *Validation* to *True* before you return from the method, like this:

```
if int(Guess) == Number and count < 1:
    Validation = True
    return "First time right! Genius?"
```

Do this for all if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

I spot two (and a half) problems in your code:

1. As pointed out by Ishay Peled, you need to make Validation global
2. Your "return" statements are located **before** you change the value of "Validation"
3. "while" has no "else"

Here's the updated code:

```
from random import randint

count = 0
Validation = False

def generateNumber():
    Number = randint(1, 10)
    return Number

def checkNumber(Guess):
    global Validation
    Number = generateNumber()
    if int(Guess) == Number and count < 1:
        Validation = True
        return "First time right! Genius?"

    elif int(Guess) == Number and count == 2:
        Validation = True
        return "Correct. Second time, nice!"
    elif int(Guess) == Number and count < 4:
        Validation = True
        return "Correct. Good job."
    elif int(Guess) == Number and count > 3:
        Validation = True
        return "Correct. Took you long enough."
    else:
        return "Wrong! Try again "


while Validation == False:
    Guess = input("Please guess a number between 1 to 10: ")
    print (checkNumber(Guess))
    print "validation: %s" % str(Validation)
    count += 1

TryAgain = input("Would you like to try again? y/n \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the global variable issue, you need to make another set of fixes. All your assignments to Validation = True appear after the "return" statements. The Validation = True will never execute! It will exit the function before executing those. Set 'Validation = True' before you 'return'. You still need to have the global declaration as Ishay stated.